# why do we calculate risk when we already have loss functions?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, risk

If we already have let's say mean squared error as a loss function which can tell how good our algorithm is, then why we calculate the expectation of loss function as Risk?

Apologies, if this a naive question since i am new to machine learning.

Comment: *Berger, James O. Statistical decision theory and Bayesian analysis. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.* said that calculation of risk is compatible with the rational axioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk in machine learning context is the expectation of the loss function over the random variable.

Let's say you have a random variable $x$. If you apply the loss function $L(.)$ to this random variable you get another random variable $y=L(x)$. The expectation is not a function, it's rather an operator $E[.]$, when you apply it on the random variable $y$ you get the constant value $\mu=E[y]$.

So, the result of applying a loss function is the transformation of the random input into another random input. When you get the expectation of that new (transformed) random variable, you get back a number -- risk.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on your distinction between function and operator? As it seems the definition of an operator is highly dependent on a specific field or context.

Comment: You can look at an operator as a function where the inputs are other functions. For instance, expectation $E[x]=\int_X x dx$ accepts not just a particular value of $x$, but operates on an entire domain of $x$. However, you could look at the entire domain of $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ as a point in a space of functions. Then expectation becomes a function that accepts that one point and returns a point in real space

Answer (score 11):

Here is my basic(!) explanation.

You are totally correct that the loss function can be used to calculate how good (or bad) your algorithm is. However, it does so by using the *known data set*, or the data used to train the algorithm.

Risk is the expectation of the loss function. This expectation applies to all input data, not just the data that you used.

You might have an extremely good algorithm under your first definition through overfitting. Say you are predicting college acceptance of students. You have a sample of 100 students with different variables: gpa, sat, and high school ranking. Your algorithm is completely over trained to the data and consists of a saying that for those exact inputs, you'd produce those exact output scores.

But what if you get a new student? In that case your classifer wouldn't have trained against it, and would produce an incorrect answer. Of the total input space, your 100 samples are nothing. Your risk in this case would be extremely high (infinity). Your model would be terrible in reality and that is exactly what risk measures.

Comment: AFAIK: Since we will never have the complete distribution of all data... we mostly only calculate emperical risk, which is again calculated from the data itself.

Comment: But do you have knowledge of the underlying PDF of input data?